# Apache velocity: org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: java, apache, velocity

I am following http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075966/core-java/start-up-the-velocity-template-engine.html tutorial.

I have kept my `vm` file in the same folder as of my class. I am getting the following exception:

`Exception in thread "main" org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource`

As `velocity` documentation says I need `JSP/servlet` support which I don't have right now.

Where am I going wrong?

PS: I am using `IntelliJ IDE`

Comment: Make sure the template is in the working directory which is probably the root of your module in IntelliJ. Double-check your runtime configuration by clicking Edit Configurations in the Run menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER` and `classpath.resource.loader.class` in your Velocity engine to look in your source code:

```
VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine();
engine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
engine.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName())

//this is at src/main/java level, tested with Netbeans
Template yourTemplate = ve.getTemplate("yourTemplate.vm");
```